# LINQ to Entities Special Database Query not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a database with two tables (UserData) and (UserDetails). I use the LINQtoEntities.
The issue here is that in the LINQ query is not accepted:

```
Details = c.ToList<UserDetails>()
```

Error is:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<mynamespace.UserDetails>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.IEnumerable>'

```
public class UserData
{

    public int Index{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string PersonalNo { get; set; }
    public <List<UserDetails>> Details { get; set; }
}

public struct UserDetails
{
    public int Age;
    public string profession;
    public string gender;
}

public IEnumerable<Userdata> GetUserData()
{
    var context = new DatabaseEntities();

    var Results =
        from a in context.UserData
        join b in context.UserDetails on a.Index equals b.Index into c
        select new UserData{ Index = a.Index, Name = a.Name, PersonalNo = a.PersonalNo, 
                             Details= c.ToList<UserDetails>() };

    return Results;          
}
```

Is there anybody who can help me out. In case more infos needed, please ask.
Thanks.

Comment: This code can't compile: `public <List<UserDetails>> Details`. Please fix that first.

Comment: Have you tried it without generic param or completly without the ToList()?
... Details= c.ToList() }
or ... Details= c}

Comment: Gert: That is my issue and the reason I asked here for help ;-)
Xaver: Not working. Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: How can you get runtime errors with code that doesn't compile??? If you can run this code it should be different that what you show here.

Answer (score 0):

The following example is working. To get it working you can use object. See below the example:

```
public class UserData
{
   public int Index{ get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string PersonalNo { get; set; }
   public List<object> Details { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails
{
   public int Age;
   public string profession;
   public string gender;
}

public IEnumerable<Userdata> GetUserData()
{
   var context = new DatabaseEntities();

   var Results =
       from a in context.UserData
       join b in context.UserDetails on a.Index equals b.Index into c
       select new UserData{ Index = a.Index, Name = a.Name, PersonalNo = a.PersonalNo, 
                            Details= c.ToList<object>() };

   return Results;          
}
```

The Type in the Watch windows is names as "object {MyTestApp.UserDetails}"
So basically it is working as I did it. But I need to cast it appropriate. Possibly now it is easier to help me.
Any suggestions?